# Nesting a group of columns with a new header in the JSON serialization

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, to-json

I have a Pandas dataframe of this kind

```
    start    end   compDepth compReleaseDepth compMeanRate
0     0.0   0.62  58.0999985              1.5          110
1    0.66   1.34  57.1399994                3           94
2    1.42    2.1  57.1399994              2.5           89
3    2.21   2.87  58.5699997              2.5           79
4    2.97   3.65  55.2399979              3.5           77
5    3.78   4.45  53.8600006              1.5           76
6    4.49   5.17  62.2700005              0.5           81
7    5.97   6.65  56.1899986              2.5           85
```

I need to serialise the data into JSON and I used `df.to_json(orient='records')` and it works fine.

However, I would like to nest the last 3 columns into a new header called `"annotations"`. This is what I want to achieve, is there a simple way to do this?

```
[{
        "start": "0.0",
        "end": "0.62",
        "annotations": {
            "compDepth": "58.0999985",
            "compReleaseDepth": "1.5",
            "compMeanRate": "110"
        }
    }, {
        "start": "0.66",
        "end": "1.34",
        "annotations": {
            "compDepth": "57.1399994",
            "compReleaseDepth": "3",
            "compMeanRate": "94"
        }
    }, {
        "start": "1.42",
        "end": "2.1",
        "annotations": {
            "compDepth": "57.1399994",
            "compReleaseDepth": "2.5",
            "compMeanRate": "89"
        }
    }, {
        "start": "2.21",
        "end": "2.87",
        "annotations": {
            "compDepth": "58.5699997",
            "compReleaseDepth": "2.5",
            "compMeanRate": "79"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to nest yourself the data in a new column using `to_dict`

```
df['annotations'] = df[['compDepth','compReleaseDepth','compMeanRate']].to_dict(orient='records')
```

Then you use `to_json(orient='records')` only on the 3 columns you want in your final output

```
df[['start','end','annotations']].to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: Indeed is a simple way! thanks a lot. One only question: I have this warning when executing your first code. Do you know why?

`__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy`

Comment: @dimstudio I don't get this warning, so I assume it's an issue with your `df`, which might be a slice of your original data or something similar. It's not link to these two lines of codes, so not sure how to help, but the link provides in the warning is a good way to understand why :)